# WPF simple bind in code behind

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

I try to learn WPF, I have problem with basic binding, at the beginning I want to set bind in code behind. May anyone know what I make wrong?

Fils CS

```
public partial class BindInCodeBehind : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _myText;

    public string MyText
    {
        get { return _myText; }
        set
        {
            _myText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyText");
        }
    }

    public BindInCodeBehind()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var bind = new Binding();
        bind.Source = MyText;
        bind.Path = new PropertyPath("Content");

        MyLabel.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, bind);

        MyText = "New tekst";
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

File XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfBindingLearn.BindInCodeBehind"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="BindInCodeBehind" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Label Name="MyLabel" Content="Wait for binding"></Label>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Path` is set in relation to current binding source. Your source (which is a `String`) does not have `Content` property. You can set `Source` to `Window` and `Path` to `MyText`

```
var bind = new Binding();
bind.Source = this;
bind.Path = new PropertyPath("MyText");
```